# Location of N max values in a python list?

Tags: python

I have a python list(containing integers), and I want to find the indices of N highest values in a list. Where N is less than the length of the list.

I can find the N maximum values by sorting the list, but is there good way to find the location of these N maximum values?

As an example, my list is a = [10, 16, 29, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15], and I need to find the location of 3 highest values.

Expected result is [2, 1, 9]

Comment: Sort the list and attach the original index?

Comment: How do you actually want the result returned? Is [2, 1, 9] correct, or any list of [1, 2, 9]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import operator
>>> lst = [10,16,29,1,4,5,7,9,13,15]
>>> indexed = list(enumerate(lst)) # attach indices to the list
>>> indexed
[(0, 10), (1, 16), (2, 29), (3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 13), (9, 15)]
# use operator.itemgetter to get the index '1' of the (index, value) tuple
>>> top_3 = sorted(indexed, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[-3:]
>>> list(reversed([i for i, v in top_3]))
[2, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple, elegant solution. Don't need to import anything or use special tools. :D

```
a = [10, 16, 29, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15]
N = 3


b = a[:]
locations = []
minimum = min(b) - 1
for i in range(N):
    maxIndex = b.index(max(b))
    locations.append(maxIndex)
    b[maxIndex] = minimum

print(locations)
```

Comment: `b = a` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. Yes, b = a[:] actually creates a new list :)

Comment: @jgritty You're right, I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out! :D

Comment: This doesn't work for a list of exclusively negative numbers, or if there are more negative numbers than N though. It is assuming 0 is lower than the N largest numbers. slightly safer is to set b[b.index(max(b))] = min(b)

Comment: @jgritty Yeah I fixed it so it sets the value to 1 less than the minimum value.

Comment: I tested all of the solutions here with varying sizes of lists and values of N. This is the fastest solution every time. Even on lists of sizes over 1 million. @SeanBreckenridge

Comment: @jgritty huh, yeah. This would be the best for time. For most of what some sort of algorithm like this would be useful, n(O(N)) is still usually less than n*log(N). Do you still have the code for that; I wouldn't mind seeing some results.

Comment: I manually tried many different combinations, could've made the code better, but I was convinced after about 10 various trials.

Comment: Also interesting that when you have an ambiguous result like your sample of data points is much smaller than the length of the list, you end with different results, for instance if the list is `a = [100, 100, 100, 100]` and you want to get the largest 3.

Comment: @jgritty ive modified the code so that min(b) is only calculated once. And all highest values are set to the same minimum value after being counted. Does this make it faster?

Comment: Ever so slightly, yes @Flaming_Dorito

Comment: @jgritty Sorry for the constant edits :p but I changed it so that it only calculates max(b) and its index once. Is it even faster now?

Comment: Yes, even faster, by a bigger margin that time. @Flaming_Dorito

Comment: On a list of 10 million random items ranging in size from 0 to 100 million, this method can find the largest 3 in under a second on my computer. Next closest is the pandas method that takes 2.2 seconds, and the function using the operator import takes over 12 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this easily with `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lst = pd.Series([10, 16, 29, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15])
>>> i = lst.nlargest(3)
>>> i.index.values.tolist()
[2, 1, 9]
```

Comment: This is a great example for displaying the power of pandas

Answer (score 3):

Basically what Sean Breckenridge said, but to give you the exact output you requested:

```
import operator
a = [10, 16, 29, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15]

d = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(a)}
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
result_list = [k[0] for k in sorted_d][:3]
print(result_list)
# [2, 1, 9]
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad there. Missed the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

The numpy library has tools and a functional programming paradigm that sometimes makes things like this easy.  You convert to a numpy.array type (Let’s call it x) then x.argmax() gives you the position of the largest.  Put a ‘1’ in another array of the same length that is zeros in all other places (which you do by saying index- numpy.zeros(len(x))).

From there you can figure out how to do it twice more, but excluding the values that have something other than zero in the index array.

I suspect numpy even has a method that, for a given input array, gives you the indexes sorted by increasing value. In that case it’s trivial: just take the first three indexes in the list you get from that method ( it might be .sort()).

NUMPY is definitely worth getting to know above almost all other libraries

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, as I was manipulating data frames and arrays !!

Comment: If you want to have some fun but quickly learn clever ways to coneptualize things like this, search around for an old programming language called APL.  There is an online interactive interpreter.  It was a super-powerful language that used a custom font to do a lot with 1 character and was very clever with array data.  In text this would have been 3[take][grade-down]x, where [take] was an upward pointing arrow and [grade-down] was a mathematical ‘del’ symbol with a vertical bar through it.  I believe some got ‘the game of life’ implemented in one line of code.